# MVC3 Url.Action querystring generation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, url, razor, query-string

I am trying to generate an url for an MVC 3 action within javascript environment (in a cshtml file).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  ...
  var src = "@Url.Action("GetProductImage", new { productId = Model.Product.Id, pos = 1, size = 0 })";
  $(document.createElement("img")).attr("src", src);
  ...
</script>
```

Now this works almost fine, my problem is that the querystring is being escaped.
Instead of:

```
"/Products/GetProductImage?productId=1&pos=0&size=0"
```

it generates:

```
"/Products/GetProductImage?productId=1&amp;pos=0&amp;size=0"
```

so my action does not get called.

Now I know I can make my own custom Url helper function, but I was wondering if I can use this or some other built in helper to get the unescaped URL?

Thanks in advance, G.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var src = "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("GetProductImage", new { productId = Model.Product.Id, pos = 1, size = 0 }))";
   $(document.createElement("img")).attr("src", src);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I had the same problem :)
Though it should be @HtmlRaw(Url.Action(/*...*/)) rather than @HtmlRaw(HtmlUrl.Action(/*...*/))

Answer (score 5):

```
var src = "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("GetProductImage", new { productId = Model.Product.Id, pos = 1, size = 0 }))";
```

Url.Action worked for me **not** HtmlUrl.Action

Enjoy!