# How to get two input values to two parameters in MVC View Button OnClick method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to get values to two parameters in Button OnClick method.

```
<input type="button" id="btnAddtoGrid" value="Add" class="btn btn-group" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ServiceDetails", "ServiceHeaders")?Remark='+ $('#txtRemarks').val(),?Cost='+ $('#txtCost').val()" />
<input type="button" id="btnAddtoGrid" value="Add" class="btn btn-group" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ServiceDetails", "ServiceHeaders")?Remark='+ $('#txtRemarks').val()'+'?Cost='+ $('#txtCost').val()" />
<input type="button" id="btnAddtoGrid" value="Add" class="btn btn-group" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ServiceDetails", "ServiceHeaders")?Remark='+ $('#txtRemarks').val() & ?Cost='+ $('#txtCost').val()" />
<input type="button" id="btnAddtoGrid" value="Add" class="btn btn-group" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ServiceDetails", "ServiceHeaders")?Remark='+ $('#txtRemarks').val():?Cost='+ $('#txtCost').val()" />
<input type="button" id="btnAddtoGrid" value="Add" class="btn btn-group" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ServiceDetails", "ServiceHeaders")?Remark='+ $('#txtRemarks').val() && ?Cost='+ $('#txtCost').val()" />    
<input type="button" id="btnAddtoGrid" value="Add" class="btn btn-group" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ServiceDetails", "ServiceHeaders")?Remark='+ $('#txtRemarks').val(),?Cost='+ $('#txtCost').val()" />
```

I need to get txtRemarks & txtCost textbox values into two parameters on Button OnClick method.

Comment: Here is how you can append query string to the @Url.Action : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872157/mvc3-url-action-querystring-generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872157/mvc3-url-action-querystring-generation)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your requirement by jQuery like this

Update cshtml

```
<input type="text" id="txtRemarks" value="Test" />
<input type="text" id="txtCost" value="10" />
<input type="button" id="btnAddtoGrid" value="Add" class="btn btn-group" />
<input type="button" id="btnAddtoGrid" value="Add" class="btn btn-group" />
<input type="button" id="btnAddtoGrid" value="Add" class="btn btn-group" />
<input type="button" id="btnAddtoGrid" value="Add" class="btn btn-group" />
<input type="button" id="btnAddtoGrid" value="Add" class="btn btn-group" />
<input type="button" id="btnAddtoGrid" value="Add" class="btn btn-group" />
```

Add script tag to cshtml

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       updateAttr();
    });
    $("#txtRemarks, #txtCost").change(function() {
        updateAttr();
    });

    function updateAttr() {
        $('input[type="button"]').each(function(index, item) {

            var onclick = 'location.href=';
            onclick += '@Url.Action("ServiceDetails", "ServiceHeaders")';

            onclick += "?Remark=" + $('#txtRemarks').val();
            onclick += "?Cost=" + $('#txtCost').val();
            $(item).attr('onclick', onclick);
        });
    }

</script>
```

I tested and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I would rely on the standard ASP.NET MVC helpers:

**chtml**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddServiceHeaders", "ServiceDetails", FormMethod.Post))  
{ 
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Remark)  
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cost)  

    <input type="button" id="btnAddtoGrid" value="Add" class="btn btn-group" />
}
```

**c#**

```
public sealed class Model {
    public string Remark { get; set; }
    public int Cost { get; set; }
}

public class ServiceDetailsController : Controller {

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddServiceHeaders(Model model){
        // ..
    }

}
```

See [example: Music Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-5).

*I would recommend to*:

- use POST-verb for any data update (pass params to the server in the request body, not the query string)
- use input-validation
- protect your data from malicious actions - see [AntiForgeryToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view)